# Pandas merge. right_on join column is being added to the result

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing a simple merge in Pandas. The strange part is that in the column on which I am joining from the right dataframe ends up in the result. So I have twice the same info in different columns and have to drop it.

```
df1.merge(df2.reset_index().rename(columns={'df_name': df2_name'}),
                            left_on='df_id',
                            right_on='df2_id').drop('df2_id', axis=1).set_index('index')
```

As you can see I have to drop df2_id at the end because I end up with dataframe containing both df_id and df2_id.

Isn't it normal the column df2_id not to be added to the result of the merge as it is being used as key?

Comment: Hi MitakaJ9, then what is your question?

Comment: Isn't it normal the column df2_id not to be added to the result of the merge as it is being used as key?

Comment: @MitakaJ9 no it will appear, check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected result.

If the names are different both columns will be kept.